# Verilog: Shift Register with feedback loop

Tags: verilog, shift-register, vlsi

I am trying to simulate a 3 stage shift register with feedback loop using D-flipflop and XOR gate.

main.v:

```
module main(
d0,d1,d2,
 clk ,
 reset ,
 q0,q1,q2);

input clk,reset;

inout d0,d1,d2,q0,q1,q2;

dff df1(.d(d0),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.q(q0));

dff df2(.d(q0),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.q(q1));

dff df3(.d(q1),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.q(q2));
xor1 exor1(.a(q1), .b(q2), .c(d0));
endmodule
```

dff.v:

```
module dff(
d,
 clk,
 reset,
 q);

input d,clk,reset;
output q;

reg q;

always @ ( posedge clk)
 if (~reset) begin
   q <= d;
 end  else begin
   q <= 1'b0;
 end

endmodule
```

main_tb.v:

```
module main_tb;
reg clk,reset;
 //reg d0,d1,d2,q0,q1,q2;
 wire d0,d1,d2,q0,q1,q2;
 initial
 begin
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    #15
    reset = 0;

 end



always begin
    #5 clk = !clk;
    end
    main U0(
 .d0(d0),
 .d1(d1),
 .d2(d2),
 .clk(clk),
 .reset(reset),
 .q0(q0),
 .q1(q1),
 .q2(q2)
 );
```

endmodule

Now ISim doesnt simulate this code. Where am i going wrong?

EDIT: edited the testbench code. ISim is stuck at 0ps.[image]

Comment: Just for reference, the standard format for registers with synchronous reset is: `always @ ( posedge clk)
 if (reset) begin
   q <= 1'b0;
 end  else begin
   q <= d;
 end`. Synthesis tools are better at recognising logic when you stick to the standard patterns.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: It doesn't matter. To a synthesis tool, your version and the OP's version are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `reset` signal in your code, but you never actually assert it.

Without that, the simulator cannot put the FFs into a known state, so they just show "unknown" forever.

Assigning values to your `q` wires in the testbench is useless — that just conflicts with the values that the `dff`s are trying to produce.

Comment: So all the values get initialized in ISim, but the 'Run' button is greyed out

Comment: Hey @Dave Tweed, Any idea on how to 'Run' it.

Comment: In any LFSR if you reset to 0's then feedback must be inverted to D, otherwise it is stuck and that it wont work.  If inverted feedback then all 1's is illegal for initial condition, with an odd number of XOR's

Answer (score 0):

Your clock generator should be

```
 always @ // remove the (*)
    #5 clk = !clk;
```

Also, you probably want to use a procedural `force` statement and then `release` the intermediate q signals.

Comment: Where should I add force statement? In main.v or in main_tb.v?

Comment: In main_tb. You want to force the q0-1 for at least one clock cycle to get the shift register into a known state, then release them

Comment: `initial
  begin
  clk = 0;
  reset = 0;
   force U0.d0 = 1'b0;
   force U0.q0 = 1'b0;
   force U0.q1 = 1'b1;
   force U0.d1 = 1'b0;
   force U0.d2 = 1'b0;
   #5 
   release U0.d0;
   release U0.q0;
   release U0.q1;
   release U0.d1;
   release U0.d2;
  end`

Comment: Shouldn't need to force any signals, just assert the reset signal for a clock cycle or more.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you want to test the LFSR.

Comment: So all the values get initialized in ISim, but the 'Run' button is greyed out in ISim and I cant run the code.